# Href attributes are empty in Pagedlist Pagination Links

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, pagedlist

PagedListPager method is generating Pagination Links (Anchor Tags) but their href attributes are Empty/Null. See the Image

[image]

**Code in View**

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Orders", new { page, size = Model.PageSize }), new PagedListRenderOptions() { Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded })
```

**Namespaces are added**

```
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@model IPagedList<eRepository.Models.Orders>
```

Controller Method

```
public ActionResult Orders(int? page)
        {
            using (_context db = new _context())
            {
                return View(db.userorders.Where(s => s.status == 1).OrderBy(d => d.cdate).ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 10));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Take the `Url.Action("Orders", new { page, size = Model.PageSize })` out of the PagedList helper and see what that renders. It should be `Url.Action("Orders", new { page = page, size = Model.PageSize })`.

Comment: By adding page = page does nothing... But what do you mean by taking that out of the pagedlist helper ?

Comment: The Url helper needs to provide a correct url. Add it to a div so you can see the output.

Comment: is Orders an Action?

Comment: Yes Orders is a ActionResult that returns a View with list of Records

Comment: @Jasen can you show me what you wanted to say i am not getting your point.

Comment: @MohiyoDeen add @Url.Action("Orders", new { page = page, size = Model.PageSize }) inside a div so you can see the result. ex:

<div> 
@Url.Action("Orders", new { page = page, size = Model.PageSize })
</div>

Comment: Just add it to your view so you can see it independently of the pager `@Url.Action(...)`. Then show us a more complete example with your controller actions.

Comment: Well the Pagination was already inside a div but i have add just @Url.Action() and got compilation error "The name 'page' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: `page` is an integer, yes? Substitute a fixed value `page = 1`.

Comment: @Jasen i have updated Controller Method... and After adding fixed value to page and compiling i got nothing... The DIV is empty

Comment: Try a more explicit overload https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_UrlHelper_Action_System_String_System_String_System_Web_Routing_RouteValueDictionary_. The pager will be blank if you can't generate a url string.

Answer (score 2):

You should do something like this:

Controller:

```cs
public ActionResult Orders(int? page)
   {
       var model = db.Orders.ToList();
       int pageSize = 3;
       int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
       return View(model.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
   }
```

View:

```cs
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc

@model IPagedList<Store.Models.Orders>


@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }), new PagedListRenderOptions() { Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded })
```

Comment: I have updated question with controller... and your solution doesn't seem to be working... Still the same result Paginations links are created but without href values...

Comment: Maybe you should try to add controllerName in Url.Action :


@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index","ControllerName", new { page }), new PagedListRenderOptions() { Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded })

Comment: That also gives the same error... I wonder on a different view of the same controller links are working but not on this View... while everything looks fine